# Task switcher lags animation

Tags: eos6

The animation of the multitasking mode and window switching on the integrated INTEL graphics is terribly slow. Everything is fine on the external NVIDIA card, but I need Intel

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the brand and model of computer you’re using (1) the Terminal output of `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'`. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)

Comment: `OS: elementary OS 6 Odin x86_64 `
`Host: Laptop ASUS G550JK 1.0 `
`Kernel: 5.15.6-xanmod1 `
`CPU: Intel i5-4200H (4) @ 3.400GHz `
`GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor  Memory: 3295MiB / 11861MiB `